# SQL Display student record having maximum marks from other table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
student(sID,sNAME,sCLASS);
result(sID,subMARKS);
```

Actually, in MS-ACCESS, i am trying to this with equi join but getting wrong result. i'm writting my query like

```
SELECT stud.sID
     , stud.sNAME
     , stud.sCLASS
     , result.sID 
  FROM student
     , result 
 WHERE(SELECT MAX(subMARKS) FROM result)
```

It should display Ali record only because he is having maximum marks. but i am getting this kind of output as shown in picture below.

```
sID sNAME sCLASS
  1 Ali   BSC
  2 Ahmad FSC
  3 Asgar ICS
  4 Akram BSC
```

Comment: Access, or mysql? Make your mind up

Comment: And what's an "equi join "... I see no joins in your code. Meanwhile your WHERE clause is missing an actual condition

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data (e.g., data that would make it clear why Ali should be returned)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.SID, T1.sname FROM student T1
LEFT JOIN resultT2 ON t1.sid=t2.sid
WHERE t2.submarks = (SELECT Max(submarks) FROM result);
```